# Playing audio in SAP Web IDE

Tags: html, audio, sap-web-ide

i am trying to play a mp3-file in the SAP Web IDE but can't get it working.

```
    var audio = new Audio("sound/beep.mp3");
    audio.play();
```

It does not seem that the IDE is even loading the soundfile.
Do i have to add something in the preload config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution on [SCN](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2014/07/21/give-an-errorwarning-sound-to-the-user-when-an-error-occurs-in-application)

They add the audio tag in the index.html:

```
<body class="sapUiBody">  
  <div id="content"></div>  
  <audio id="idErrorSound">  
    <source src="audio/ErrorSound.mp3"></source>  
  </audio>  
</body>
```

and then load it by the given id like this:

```
function playErrorSound() {  
    var audio = document.getElementById("idErrorSound");  
    audio.play();  
}
```